# Angular 7 component. 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: angular, routes, components, router

I have a component called r, which receives via querystring a parameter called a. when I try it from VS Code it works perfectly.
Later I publish it on my server using windows and IIS and I open the page https://mypage/r?A= Fl, the browser returns 404 - File or directory not found. But the R component exists.

How could you solve this? I appreciate your help.

Comment: did you try production build of your app? Read [Deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Comment: Yes, the command I execute is: ng build --outputPath = dist / --prod = true

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it, I needed to add the following to the web.config file.

```
    <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
    <configuration>

    <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
         <rules>
           <rule name = "Angular Routes" stopProcessing = "true">
             <match url = ". *" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping = "MatchAll">
               <add input = "{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType = "IsFile" negate = "true" />
               <add input = "{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType = "IsDirectory" negate = "true" />
             </ conditions>
             <action type = "Rewrite" url = "./ index.html" />
           </ rule>
         </ rules>
       </ rewrite>
    </system.webServer>

    </ configuration>
```

Comment: Good you figured it out. I hope the documentation was helpful. :)